# Relative path and file_exists() when called from a required file?

Tags: php, path, require, relative-path, file-exists

I've written a tiny MVC framework for a project. I'm using Twig as the template engine, but I'm having trouble validating whether a view exists or not.

This is a snippet from the file which Controller class is defined in...

```
    protected function renderView($viewFile, $viewData = [])
    {
      if (file_exists($this->appPath . "views/$viewFile"))
      {
        echo $this->twig->render($viewFile, $viewData);
      }
      else
        return false;
    }
```

The problem is that the `file_exists()` call that checks whether a view exists is not working. The `appPath` property is defined when the controller is constructed. It is the **path relative to the file where the controller is being instantiated**.

An `index.php` file is located in the framework's root directory. There is an `init.php` which loads all of the core classes, like the `Controller` class. `init.php` is required into `index.php`. `init.php` requires some configuration files, auto-loaders, and the core classes (Like `Controller`).

I have confirmed with `getcwd()` that the current working directory when this method is called is correct. I have also echoed out the path that the method is attempting to check. The path that I'm feeding to `file_exists`is indeed the correct relative path from the current working directory.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Does `$this->appPath` have a trailing `/`?

Comment: @Mark Baker Yes, it does have a trailing /.

Comment: So is `$this->appPath` a full filesystem path? or a relative path from your to your current working directory (`getcwd()`)? (Note that current working directory isn't necessarily relative to your controller's class file)

Comment: Right. `getcwd()` returns the directory which contains `index.php` which is where this controller is being instantiated. `$this->appPath` returns something like `../package_manager/`. That is the correct relative path to the app directory which contains the `views` directory...relative to `index.php`.

Comment: I should also say that the URL in this case looks something like `http://domain.com/Ignition_V2/ignition/ignition/notfound`. Apache turns the URL into `GET` variables...however, this hasn't cause a problem with `file_exists()` in other places in the framework.

Comment: The first thing to do in order to surely orientate where the issue resides is to add `echo $this->appPath . "views/$viewFile";` just before `if (file_exists(...))`. Then: 1) if this output doesn't look as expected, continue finely analyzing the current values of `$this->appPath` and `$viewFile`; 2) otherwise continue with modifying `if (file_exists(...))` where `...` is the hard coded value of the involved path...